# Keyboard focus problems

Tags: wpf, winforms, dotnetbrowser

I am needing to use the DotNetBrowserControl inside of another application (I am an add-in in the application). The application is written in WPF and has some WinForms components.

- When I try to use the WPFBrowserView in the app I can never get focus to go into the Browser Window at all (even when clicking on a the google search box for example).
- When I try to use the WinformsBrowserView inside of a WindowsFormsHost control I am able to get focus into the google search box by clicking on it. However once I click focus out of the browser control (to a WPF textbox for example) I can never get Keyboard focus back into the browser (even when clicking on a textbox in the browser).

It seams I am closest on getting the WInformsBrowserView working. Does anyone have any advice on how to force focus into the browser window? Even if I could programmatically force this to happen it would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented force focus feature for DotNetBrowser, but it is not yet present in the current version. We plan to add it to the next version of DotNetBrowser. If you need a build with this feature present, please get in touch with us via DotNetBrowser support email, and we will provide you with a preview build.

Comment: If you are having one of the latest versions of DotNetBrowser 1.x, you can use the following statement to force the keyboard focus to the heavyweight WinFormsBrowserView: `browserView.Focused = true;`

Comment: In addition, switching to the lightweight rendering mode usually resolves this issue without any additional workarounds.